# changing input to uppercase and posting it to mysql database

Tags: php, html

User needs to type an input and this is the code:

```
Ime projekta: <input type="text" class="normal" name="ime_projekta" size="20" maxlength="20" style="text-transform:uppercase" /><br><br>
<input type="submit" class="like" value="OK" />
```

This works! When i type all characters all upper case (caps lock off). But! This is later posted to database and when i check my database all my inputs are lowercase.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `text-transform` only changes the apperance on the client side. When the text is recieved by the backend, it's still lowercase. You will have to apply an uppercase function ([strtoupper](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php)) to your text using php.

Answer (score 0):

Use php function `strtoupper($_POST['input_name'])`, before mysql update.